# Variance of the Kalman filtering

Tags: kalman-filter, noise

Having the scalar system:
\begin{cases}
      x(t+1)=ax(t)+b\eta(t)\\
      y(t)=cx(t)+d\xi(t)
    \end{cases}
where $\eta(t)=\text{WN}(0,1)$ and $\xi(t)=\text{WN}(0,1)$ are uncorrelated noises.

Why if $d=0$ and $c\neq0$, the variance of the Kalman filtering error is zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the prediction step the variance of the estimate of $x(t)$ would be non-zero, assuming $b\neq0$. However, during the correction step the measurement $y(t)$ in this case allows one to perfectly reconstruct $x(t)$, since when $d=0$ it holds that $x(t)=y(t)/c$. The Kalman filter utilizes this information fully, which drives the variance of the estimate of $x(t)$ during this step to zero (for it to go up again in the prediction step, ect.).

In order to show this one can use the standard [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Predict) calculations. Namely, the prediction step is given by

\begin{align}
\hat{x}_{k|k-1} &= F_k\,\hat{x}_{k-1|k-1} + B_k\,u_k, \\
P_{k|k-1} &= F_k\,P_{k-1|k-1}\,F_k^\top + Q_k,
\end{align}

with in your case $F_k = a$, $B_k=0$ (there are no deterministic inputs in your system) and $Q_k = b^2$. Substituting this into the prediction equations and using that in your scalar case the matrices in the equations do commute yields

\begin{align}
\hat{x}_{k|k-1} &= a\,\hat{x}_{k-1|k-1}, \\
P_{k|k-1} &= a^2\,P_{k-1|k-1} + b^2.
\end{align}

So even if $P_{k-1|k-1} = 0$ then during the prediction phase $P_{k|k-1}$ would at least become equal to $b^2$.

Now, the correction step is given by

\begin{align}
\tilde{y}_k &= y_k - H_k\,\hat{x}_{k|k-1}, \\
S_k &= H_k\,P_{k|k-1}\,H_k^\top + R_k, \\
K_k &= P_{k|k-1}\,H_k^\top S_k^{-1}, \\
\hat{x}_{k|k} &= \hat{x}_{k|k-1} + K_k\,\tilde{y}_k, \\
P_{k|k} &= (I - K_k\,H_k)\,P_{k|k-1},
\end{align}

with in your case $H_k = c$ and $R_k = d^2 = 0$. Substituting this into the correction equations and using that in your scalar case the matrices in the equations do commute yields

\begin{align}
\tilde{y}_k &= y_k - c\,\hat{x}_{k|k-1}, \\
S_k &= c^2\,P_{k|k-1}, \\
K_k &= P_{k|k-1}\,\frac{c}{c^2\,P_{k|k-1}} = \frac{1}{c}, \\
\hat{x}_{k|k} &= \hat{x}_{k|k-1} + K_k\,\tilde{y}_k = \hat{x}_{k|k-1} + \frac{1}{c}\,(y_k - c\,\hat{x}_{k|k-1}) = \frac{y_k}{c}, \\
P_{k|k} &= (1 - K_k\,c)\,P_{k|k-1} = \left(1 - \frac{1}{c}\,c\right) P_{k|k-1} = 0.
\end{align}

It can be noted that also in the non-scalar case it is possible to get $P_{k|k} = 0$. Namely, when $R_k = 0$ and $H_k$ is a square full rank $n$ by $n$ matrix (with $n$ the number of states in $x_k$).

Comment: Can you provide some computations, please?

Comment: @Fabio I have added some calculations, which should clarify what I stated. My first answer mostly tried to give an intuition why this would be true. If certain things are still not clear, feel free the ask.