# Kalman filter with contemporaneous variable

Tags: time-series, kalman-filter

In standard Kalman filter calculations. Namely, the prediction step is given by

$\hat{x}_{k|k-1} = F_k\,\hat{x}_{k-1|k-1} + B_k\,u_k, $

$P_{k|k-1} = F_k\,P_{k-1|k-1}\,F_k^\top + Q_k$

Under this setup,

$K_k = P_{k|k-1}\,H_k^\top S_k^{-1}, \\
\hat{x}_{k|k} = \hat{x}_{k|k-1} + K_k\,\tilde{y}_k, \\
P_{k|k} = (I - K_k\,H_k)\,P_{k|k-1}$

While this is fine, in my case the equation of Kalman filter includes contemporaneous variable. More specifically, below is my equation for Kalman filter

${x}_{k|k-1} = {x}_{k-1|k-1} + {y}_{k|k-1} + W_{1, k}, \\
 {y}_{k|k-1} = {y}_{k-1|k-1} + W_{2, k} \\
W_{1, k} \sim N \left( 0, {\sigma}_{1} \right), W_{2, k} \sim N \left( 0,{\sigma}_{2} \right)$

My question is, under this setup do I need to make any adjustment in the expressions of $\hat{x}_{k|k}, P_{k|k}$ above?

Any pointer will be very helpful

Comment: I need some clarification here: are you are trying to derive the equations for your new Kalman filter's prediction step? If so, then we can derive the underlying probability distributions using your stochastic models, construct a joint distribution on the random variables (RVs) $X_{k|k-1}, X_{k-1|k-1}, Y_{k|k-1}, Y_{k-1|k-1}$ and determine the marginal distribution on $X_{k|k-1}$. However, I'm not sure what your stochastic equations are saying. You seem to use uppercase letters for RVs (for example $W_{1, k}$), is a lowercase letter a realisation of an RV?

Comment: @scj Typically for a standard KF prediction step we have ${x}_{k} = F_k\,{x}_{k-1} + noise$ (in matrix format, for e.g. involving 2 variables). But in my case I have (simplified form) ${x}_{k} = {x}_{k-1} +  {y}_{k} + noise$ as first variable and $ {y}_{k} =  {y}_{k - 1} + noise$ as second variable. My question is, under this scenario, can I still use $K_k = P_{k|k-1}\,H_k^\top S_k^{-1}, \\
\hat{x}_{k|k} = \hat{x}_{k|k-1} + K_k\,\tilde{y}_k, \\
P_{k|k} = (I - K_k\,H_k)\,P_{k|k-1} $?

Comment: Is $y_{k}$ the measurement variable? The innovation $\tilde{y}_{k}$ and innovation covariance $S_{k}$ are undefined in your equations.

Comment: @scj In the equation of standard KF i.e. ${x}_{k} = F_k\,{x}_{k-1} + noise$, I followed the notations from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164430/variance-of-the-kalman-filtering

Comment: However, in my case where I have ${x}_{k} = {x}_{k-1} +  {y}_{k} + noise$ and ${y}_{k} =  {y}_{k - 1} + noise$ (i.e. 2 variables system), my measurement variable is $x_k$. I understand, there is little confusion in the notation between standard form and my form. But I think the little difference is understandable. Please let me know if further clarification is required

Comment: So to be clear the entire state consists out of both $x_k$ and $y_k$, i.e. you have $$F_k=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ $$Q_k=\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2&0\\0&\sigma_2^2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen are you sure why the first row of  $F_k$ would be like this? Please note that as per my first equation ${x}_{k} = {x}_{k-1} +  {y}_{k} + noise$. I understand that if I had ${x}_{k} = {x}_{k-1} +  {y}_{k-1} + noise$ then only $F_k$ would take your proposed form. Actually my biggest problem is correctly setting $F_k$ as I have $y_k$ NOT $y_{k-1}$ in the first equation

Comment: I think you might be confusing two things. Namely, the model of the actual dynamics (which also contains gaussian white noises) and the prediction step (which gives the best estimate for the state at time step $k$ given al info up to and including time step $k-1$).

Comment: Can you please elaborate further? In my case, model of actual dynamics is a 2-stage equations 1) ${x}_{k} = {x}_{k-1} +  {y}_{k} + noise$ and 2) ${y}_{k} =  {y}_{k - 1} + noise$. For this system what is the prediction step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you were jumping ahead a little. Namely, you combined the dynamics with stochastic terms together with the prediction step, but the prediction step should be deterministic. And in one of your comments you mentioned that the actual considered dynamics is given by

\begin{align}
x_{k} &= x_{k-1} + y_{k} + w_{1,k} \tag{1} \\
y_{k} &= y_{k-1} + w_{2,k} \tag{2}
\end{align}

with $w_{1,k} \sim N\!\left(0, \sigma_1\right)$ and $w_{2,k} \sim N\!\left(0, \sigma_2\right)$.

When writing this into one state space equation it is important which state vector one chooses. Two logical options in my opinion would be either $z_k = \begin{bmatrix}x_k & y_k\end{bmatrix}^\top$ or $z_k = \begin{bmatrix}x_k & y_{k+1}\end{bmatrix}^\top$.

---

For the first option one has to substitute $(2)$ into $(1)$

$$
z_k = \begin{bmatrix}x_k \\ y_k\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{k-1} + y_{k-1} + w_{2,k} + w_{1,k} \\ y_{k-1} + w_{2,k}\end{bmatrix} = 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}}_{F_k} z_{k-1} + 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}w_{1,k} \\ w_{2,k}\end{bmatrix}}_\text{noise}. \tag{3}
$$

It can be noted that $(3)$ would be equivalent to replacing the noise term by just a noise vector but with covariance matrix

$$
Q_k = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_2^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 & \sigma_2^2 \\ \sigma_2^2 & \sigma_2^2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

For the second option one just have to update the indices of $(2)$

$$
z_k = \begin{bmatrix}x_k \\ y_{k+1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{k-1} + y_{k} + w_{1,k} \\ y_{k} + w_{2,k+1}\end{bmatrix} = 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}}_{F_k} z_{k-1} + 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}w_{1,k} \\ w_{2,k+1}\end{bmatrix}}_\text{noise}. \tag{3}
$$

Since the noise terms are [stationary processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) the covariance matrix of it would simply be

$$
Q_k = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_2^2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

If it is also known what is measured (and it is linear in the state) and what noise is added to it, then a normal Kalman filter can be used. Using either state space representation should yields equivalent results.